# libx11-dev cannot install

Tags: development

I run the command `sudo apt-get install libx11-dev` and it returns with an error stating :

> that the package it needs to download does not exist in the online pool. a >¨404 page not found" error.

Answer (score 2):

Try first updating packages list:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libx11-dev
```

if this don't work, please post apt-get error.